# DataGridView contents is null even if we passed something to it

Tags: c#

I have the following code

```
DataGridView dataGridViewAR = new DataGridView();
dataGridViewAR.DataSource = db.GetYearlyReport(2015); // this one returns an IEnumerable
string temp = dataGridViewAR.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

during debugging, when I hover my mouse towards dataGridViewAR.DataSource, it shows that there are 52 contents.

[image]

When I hover the contents of dataGridViewAR.DataSource, it shows the contents

[image]

But when I try to access the contents of that datagridview, it shows that there are no contents.. Rows's count is 0. Why is that?

[image]

[image]

Here is the db.GetYearlyReport code snippet

```
 public IEnumerable GetYearlyReport(int year)
        {
            db = new PACUCOADB5Entities();

            var Report = (from ap in db.Accreditor_Program
                          orderby ap.Program.Visit.Starting_Date ascending
                          where
                           ap.Program.Visit.Starting_Date.Value.Year == year
                          select new
                          {
                              ap.Program.Visit.Starting_Date,
                              ap.Program.Visit.Ending_Date,
                              ap.Program.Visit.School.Name,
                              ap.Program.Type_of_Visit,
                              ap.Program.Educational_Level,
                              ap.Program.RA_Number,
                              ap.Program.Requested_Program,
                              ap.Accreditor.Title,
                              ap.Accreditor.Surname,
                              ap.Accreditor.Given_Name,
                              ap.Accreditor.Middle_Initial,
                              ap.Assigned_Area

                          }).ToList();

            return Report;
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the markup of your grid please? It'd be relevant if you have template fields or other controls in it. In which case you need to access the cell value differently.

Comment: I didnt create the datagridiview like the controls, width and stuff,,, I just instantiated the datagridview in that print.cs class. The print.cs doesnt contain any forms. Thanks

Comment: Can I ask why you did that?

Comment: @IvanMatala sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Which print.cs class?

Comment: @Bharadwaj because DataGridView is the only class i know that uses the row/column feature. I want to use the row/column access functionality

Comment: You could have used `DataTable` or `DataSet` also!

Comment: @Dura it doesn't have any markup. I didnt add the dataGridViewAR via the toolbox. I just use the new DataGridView().

Comment: @Bharadwaj i didnt find any '.DataSource' which enables me to fill out the tables in DataTable, DataSet

Comment: If you want to use `DataGridView` you need to define number of columns and you need to add columns. Then you may get what you are trying to.

Comment: @IvanMatala Is adding the markup to your page an option?

Comment: @Bharadwaj the db.GetYearlyReport() returns a dataset/IEnumerable and I want it to be feed to the DataSet/DataTable/DataGridView, but its not appearing

Comment: @Dura what markups should we add? I currently dont have any forms.

Comment: `DataSet ds = db.GetYearlyReport(2015);` and check `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;`

Comment: @Bharadwaj i get the following error: http://puu.sh/ehfSt/a810776ed7.png

Comment: Can't see the image, what you getting?

Comment: @Bharadwaj Cannot implicitly convert type 'IEnumerable' to 'DataSet'

Comment: @Bharadwaj the code for GetYearlyReport() is above

Comment: use `var` as `var v = db.GetYearlyReport(2015);` and check what type is that `v` is.

Comment: @Bharadwaj IEnumrable.. but i cant access v.rows/colums.

Comment: use `Immidiate Window` and try to get what is inside `v`

Comment: @Bharadwaj heres the immediate window  http://puu.sh/ehgQf/db868c6645.png   (if you cant see, just enter the captcha),, how do we access those?

Comment: @Bharadwaj http://imgur.com/Mp9U7mq